# Steering wheel controls with non-iPod audio player in Nissan Sentra 2012

Tags: nissan, audio, sentra

I have a 2012 Nissan Sentra SR (USA), with the default head unit that has an iPod cable. Ever since maybe iOS 5 or 6, it hasn't reliably connected with my iPod touch (a 4th gen and a 5th gen), and when I had an Android phone, I (obviously) couldn't connect it to the iPod port. I have an iPhone now, but with the current iOS, I'm still not able to use it reliably.

What usually happens is that the iPod/iPhone isn't detected as connected, or if I try to play something it just says end file or hangs.

Is there an adapter I can install so I can use any phone and still use steering wheel controls (without replacing the head unit)? If not, I have to use an aux cable, which isn't the end of the world, but I like having steering wheel controls.

Comment: Have you asked your Nissan Garage / Dealer if there is an update to the software running in the default head unit? It may be that the incompatibility is that side...

Comment: @SolarMike - I did not. This is the base head unit (no navigation or anything), so I'd be surprised if there was something of the sort. I'll ask at the Nissan dealer later this week.

Comment: I only pointed out this possibility as you have stated it worked fine with and / or before IOS 5 or 6. I don't think navigation capability or lack of it is the issue.